# Euclideon Unlimited Details Voxel Engine Architecture

Tags: raytracing, volumetric, voxelization, bounding-volume-hierarchy, volume-rendering

As I understand Euclideon haven't just rendered voxels for these infamous demos, since the amount of geometry is still too large for the 2010 PC with software raytracer and the model taking whole HDD and streaming non-stop, even with the prebaked lights. They instead did subreferencing inside their BVH to point to either dynamic generator or the instances of the pregenerated microgeometry (similar to reusing the same texture with polygonal graphics). So Euclideon could have even the dust particles on the ground. That is apparently very old trick. I remember it being used to prerender the backgrounds in Ecstatica (an old DOS video game). Am I correct? Then why have Euclideon generated so much hatred and controversy back then? The tech looks solid and was used previously for offline rendering. Euclideon people just brought it into realtime on consumer PCs.

Comment: "Am I correct? Then why have Euclideon generated so much hatred and controversy back then?" I think this is hard to answer. There are a lot of possible reasons why people like or dislike something. Maybe somebody can provide you a list of the main pro and con arguments if that is what you are looking for. However, I think this question is more or less opinion-based. This is why I am voting to close the question in its current form. Maybe you can reformulate it and ask for something that can be answered with facts.

Comment: Would a speculative post like "How does Euclideon work" be acceptable ? I think the topic itself is interesting enough.

Comment: @wychmaster are there any facts on why the new technologies get accepted or not? It is understandable when people come out to protest against say self driving cars, but 3d rendering seems like a neutral subject and apolitical subject. So there should not be any overly emotional response. So Euclideon can be a nice case study on presenting your project or research, while avoiding controversy. I.e. what they did wrong.

Comment: @PaulHK What is acceptable and what not is decided by the votes of the community :) - On other SE sites questions like "How does XY work/do AB" are generally closed for being opinion-based because the only people who know for sure are the developers. However, you can easily modify those questions into "How can I  achieve AB to get a similar effect as XY". This can be answered by anybody with the knowledge to do it. The answers you get might not do it exactly the same way as XY, but they should give the same results. So it's not about "what" you ask, but "how".

Comment: @NashGold The SE networks Q&A format is meant to be fact-based and not opinion-based. However, deciding which question is opinion-based is opinion-based itself most of the time. To make a decision, SE gives every higher reputation user (500+ on this site) the privilege to vote for closure and see the total number of votes. 5 closure votes close the question. It is a democratic decision. So other users might see it differently and the question stays open. If I vote for closure, I always leave a comment to explain the reasons for the questioner and other reviewers.